# Not able to run the helidon java jar in oracle linux 8

Tags: java, jar, helidon

I have a helidon MP java project with helidon 3.1.0 and I'm facing the issue below when I'm trying to run the generated jar file in oracle linux 8 machine where as same jar file works in other machines. Here are the details.
java version: 17.0.6
helidon version: 3.1.0
OS : Oracle linux 8
Thanks for your support in advance.

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.fromBuildTimeInitializer(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:65)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.lambda$get$1(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:56)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.access(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:91)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.get(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:53)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainer.instance(HelidonContainer.java:48)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.server.Server$Builder.build(Server.java:190)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.server.Server.create(Server.java:83)
    at oracle.communications.sam.performance.KpiApplication.main(KpiApplication.java:61)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Property IFS+x used in expression () { unset _mlshdbg;
 if [ "${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}" = '1' ]; then
 case "$-" in
 *v*x*)
 set +vx;
 _mlshdbg='vx'
 ;;
 *v*)
 set +v;
 _mlshdbg='v'
 ;;
 *x*)
 set +x;
 _mlshdbg='x'
 ;;
 *)
 _mlshdbg=''
 ;;
 esac;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${IFS+x}" ]; then
 _mlIFS=$IFS;
 fi;
 IFS=' ';
 for _mlv in ${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};
 do
 if [ "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}" -a "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv#[0-9]}" ]; then
 if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'}'`' ";
 fi;
 _mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlrv':-}'`' ";
 fi;
 done;
 if [ -n "${_mlre:-}" ]; then
 eval `eval ${_mlre} /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash '"$@"'`;
 else
 eval `/usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash "$@"`;
 fi;
 _mlstatus=$?;
 if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then
 IFS=$_mlIFS;
 else
 unset IFS;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${_mlshdbg:-}" ]; then
 set -$_mlshdbg;
 fi;
 unset _mlshdbg;
 return $_mlstatus
} does not exist
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.lambda$format$14(MpConfigImpl.java:421)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.format(MpConfigImpl.java:421)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.processExpressions(MpConfigImpl.java:399)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.resolveReferences(MpConfigImpl.java:379)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.lambda$findConfigValue$12(MpConfigImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.findConfigValue(MpConfigImpl.java:340)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.optionalValue(MpConfigImpl.java:191)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.getOptionalValue(MpConfigImpl.java:131)
    at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigProviderResolver$ConfigDelegate.getOptionalValue(MpConfigProviderResolver.java:356)
    at io.helidon.integrations.datasource.cdi.AbstractDataSourceExtension.initializeMasterProperties(AbstractDataSourceExtension.java:233)
    at io.helidon.integrations.datasource.cdi.AbstractDataSourceExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(AbstractDataSourceExtension.java:293)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:168)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
    at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:467)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.init(HelidonContainerImpl.java:214)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:137)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.initInContext(HelidonContainerImpl.java:135)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.create(HelidonContainerImpl.java:127)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.lambda$createContainer$2(BuildTimeInitializer.java:63)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.accessContainer(BuildTimeInitializer.java:72)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.createContainer(BuildTimeInitializer.java:62)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.<clinit>(BuildTimeInitializer.java:37)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.fromBuildTimeInitializer(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:65)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.lambda$get$1(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:56)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.access(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:91)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.ContainerInstanceHolder.get(ContainerInstanceHolder.java:53)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainer.instance(HelidonContainer.java:48)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.server.Server$Builder.build(Server.java:190)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.server.Server.create(Server.java:83)
    at oracle.communications.sam.performance.KpiApplication.main(KpiApplication.java:61)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:467)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.init(HelidonContainerImpl.java:214)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:137)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.initInContext(HelidonContainerImpl.java:135)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.HelidonContainerImpl.create(HelidonContainerImpl.java:127)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.lambda$createContainer$2(BuildTimeInitializer.java:63)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.accessContainer(BuildTimeInitializer.java:72)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.createContainer(BuildTimeInitializer.java:62)
    at io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.BuildTimeInitializer.<clinit>(BuildTimeInitializer.java:37)
    ... 8 more
    Suppressed: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Property IFS+x used in expression () { unset _mlshdbg;
 if [ "${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}" = '1' ]; then
 case "$-" in
 *v*x*)
 set +vx;
 _mlshdbg='vx'
 ;;
 *v*)
 set +v;
 _mlshdbg='v'
 ;;
 *x*)
 set +x;
 _mlshdbg='x'
 ;;
 *)
 _mlshdbg=''
 ;;
 esac;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${IFS+x}" ]; then
 _mlIFS=$IFS;
 fi;
 IFS=' ';
 for _mlv in ${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};
 do
 if [ "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}" -a "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv#[0-9]}" ]; then
 if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'}'`' ";
 fi;
 _mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlrv':-}'`' ";
 fi;
 done;
 if [ -n "${_mlre:-}" ]; then
 eval `eval ${_mlre} /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash '"$@"'`;
 else
 eval `/usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash "$@"`;
 fi;
 _mlstatus=$?;
 if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then
 IFS=$_mlIFS;
 else
 unset IFS;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${_mlshdbg:-}" ]; then
 set -$_mlshdbg;
 fi;
 unset _mlshdbg;
 return $_mlstatus
} does not exist
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.lambda$format$14(MpConfigImpl.java:421)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.format(MpConfigImpl.java:421)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.processExpressions(MpConfigImpl.java:399)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.resolveReferences(MpConfigImpl.java:379)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.lambda$findConfigValue$12(MpConfigImpl.java:340)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.findConfigValue(MpConfigImpl.java:340)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.optionalValue(MpConfigImpl.java:191)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigImpl.getOptionalValue(MpConfigImpl.java:131)
        at io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfigProviderResolver$ConfigDelegate.getOptionalValue(MpConfigProviderResolver.java:356)
        at io.helidon.integrations.datasource.cdi.AbstractDataSourceExtension.initializeMasterProperties(AbstractDataSourceExtension.java:233)
        at io.helidon.integrations.datasource.cdi.AbstractDataSourceExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(AbstractDataSourceExtension.java:293)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:168)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
        at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:125)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
        ... 19 more```
````

Comment: A simple google returns the following link for MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:

https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module.html#mconfig-silent_shell_debug

So it looks like the value of MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG is messing up something within Helidon which could be trying to introspect the property value looking for ${} expressions to expand.

Answer (score 1):

`MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG` appears to be an [environment variable](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module.html#mconfig-silent_shell_debug) defined to a shell script in your specific shell. If you look carefully, you will notice an expression "`${IFS+x}`" which matches the syntax of [token expected by Helidon](https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/se/config/advanced-configuration#filters-and-overrides). This is unfortunate but it looks like you would need to unset the environment variables carrying token-like expressions: ${ref} if you want to use environment variables as a configuration source (which you are very likely to need for any K8s deployments)

If this is a VM, resetting the offending envs in the execution shell might be a workaround. If this happens within the docker image, consider using a different base image that does not contain those modules.

Meanwhile, you may try your luck by filing a bug report on Helidon config requesting Helidon to ignore token-like expressions for values derived from environment and system properties, as it is highly unlikely they are substitution tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some exported shell function in your environment.

You can try to remove environment variables with names like `BASH_FUNC_`, either manually, one by one or with something like this:

`unset -f $(env | cut -d '=' -f1 | grep BASH_FUNC_)`